# libhdf5_hl.so.9 cannot open shared object file

Tags: python-3.x, hdf5, deep-learning, caffe

While running `classify.py` file ,I am getting:

`Import Error libhdf5_hl.so.9 cannot open shared object file`

It's very difficult for me to understand this error. I thought this error was just because of anaconda so I updated anaconda.. still getting the same error.. I don't know why this error is coming. please help me. Thanks in advance.

Comment: have you installed hdf5? with "dev"?

Comment: @Shai yes, I have installed.